# where is /usr/include/unistd.h and limit.h from, glibc or kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, libc

We know that unistd.h is an important header, however I am not sure if it comes from kernel source or it is installed until we install libc?

Comment: It comes from the libc source; unistd.h is a POSIX standard header; anything from the kernel will get included by this if needed. you should not use the kernel unistd.h for anything except kernel programming :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fedora

```
# rpm -qf /usr/include/unistd.h
eglibc-headers-2.13-2.21.i686
```

we can see this part in header file

```
this file is part of the GNU C Library.
```

and in the kernel version 2.6.32.21 we can see

```
/* kernel/include/linux/unistd.h */
#include <asm/unistd.h>
```

we suppose X86

```
/* kernel/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd.h */
# ifdef CONFIG_X86_32
#  include "unistd_32.h"
# else
#  include "unistd_64.h"
# endif
```

and in the file there is system call. not we normally use unistd.h

```
/*
 * This file contains the system call numbers.
 */

#define __NR_restart_syscall      0
#define __NR_exit         1
#define __NR_fork         2
#define __NR_read         3
#define __NR_write        4
#define __NR_open         5
#define __NR_close        6
#define __NR_waitpid          7
#define __NR_creat        8
```

Comment: Very useful hint. I try it on mine, it says  glibc-headers

Comment: But here is a further question, whether the content in these files defined by kernel or defined by glibc. What I thought is these files are platform and distribution specific, so, I think there must be a place for kernel to store these similar information.

Comment: in the glibc, I think it can get the system environment, just like platform and distribution version. kernel don't need to store the information for user space.It's unreasonable